# Copy figure AND legend in matlab gui

Tags: matlab

I got a GUI showing several plots. now i'd like to get one of these... "main_plot" for example (the entire figure with title, axes-descriptions AND the legend) and export it to a file. this is what i got so far:

```
function main_plot_exp_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

f_tmp = figure('visible','off');

set(f_tmp,'Units', 'Normalized', 'OuterPosition', [0 0 1 1]); 

copyobj(handles.main_plot,f_tmp);

set(gca,'Position',[0.16125 0.09 0.684375 0.84],...
    'GridLineStyle','--');


print(f_tmp, '-djpeg', 'name', '-r300');
close(f_tmp);
```

generally works like a charm EXCEPT for the damn legend, which appears to get lost in the process. any suggestions or ideas? thanks in advance!

(side question: is there anything like "gcf" only for a CERTAIN and not the current figure?)

Comment: Why are you making a copy of the `main_plot` figure to the `f_tmp`?  Why not just do `print(handles.main_plot,'-djpeg', 'name', '-r300');`?  As for your side question, if you have the figure handle (which you may from handles.main_plot) then you can use that handle.

Comment: because i'm adding a textbox to the figure (which is not there in the gui-plot) and then export. your suggestion yields "Handle Graphics handle must be a Figure." error message also, as handles.main_plot is an axis handle, which is the problem for me dealing with gui-figures. i'm not aware of a method of getting figure-handles here...

Comment: Since `handles.main_plot` is an axis handle, then try the `export_fig` code from the MATLAB File Exchange - [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig).  That may do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your procedure and faced no problem (my matlab: 8.2.0.701 (R2013b))

The best you could do as follow

```
hSome = findobj(handles.main_plot);
get(hSome,'Tag')
```

Results should yield one "legend" string. If not, replace findobj with findall. Otherwise your legend handle is stocked somewhere else and you need to look deeper into your GUI.

Comment: think it's in GUI deepspace... your procedure either yields empty strings or: 'LegendColorbarLayout','LegendColorbarLayout','LegendDeleteProxy' with findall. i got 8.0.0.783 2012b... not really trying to get the separate legend, but rather get ALL the settings from the main_plot at once. thanks for the help though

Comment: I don't know how much time you have (I assume little), but I'd advise you to make all of your GUIs from scratch using oriented object programming. There is a very nice example of such a GUI online: http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2012/11/02/imageviewer-a-gui-for-viewing-and-interactively-exploring-image-files/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the legend being lost in the process. The best I could do to overcome this was to re-create the legend in the new figure before saving it. Here an example of the code I used:

```
% find the legend(s) - I suppose in the following that there is only one legend in the GUI
L1 = findobj(handles.figure1,'tag','legend'); % where handles.figure1 is the GUI figure handle

% retrieve the legend strings and location
legendstr=get(L1,'String');
legendloc=get(L1,'Location');

% handle to the GUI axes to be saved
ax = handles.axes1;   

% create a new figure
fig = figure('Units','centimeters','outerposition',[2 2 17 17]);

% copy the GUI axes into the new figure
new_axes = copyobj(ax, fig);

set(new_axes,'Units','normalized','Position',[0.1 0.1 0.8 0.8]);

% recreate the legend
legend(new_axes,legendstr,'Location',legendloc);

%save the files in .fig and .format files (.format = .jpg, .png, ...)
hgsave(fig,[pname '\' filename]);
hgexport(fig, fname, hgexport('factorystyle'),'Format', format)
close(fig);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the axes is called main_plot, I found that the legend is referenced by:
`legend(handles.main_plot)`

So you would need to copy the legend with its parent axes (as a vector input) to the new figure:
    `copyobj([handles.main_plot legend(handles.main_plot],f_tmp);`